# How to add an additional (on top of the main) random audio track to a video using ffpmeg

Tags: batch-file, audio, video, cmd, ffmpeg

I need to add random audio tracks (1.mp3, 2.mp3, 3.mp3, 4.mp3) to video files (video1.mp4 -video10.mp4 ) using ffmpeg.

[image]

My code that doesn't work.

1. I don’t understand how to add random to a variable in cmd so that it is used as a name
2. What filters need to be set in ffmpeg so that nothing breaks

```
set /a %%R=1+5*%random%/32768

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO (

ffmpeg -i "%%G" -i "%%R".mp3 -map 0 -map 1 -c copy %%~nG.mp4

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set /A TrackNumber=%RANDOM% %% 3 + 1

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO (

ffmpeg -i "%%G" -i "%TrackNumber%.mp3" %%~nG.mp4

)
```